# Textview quebrar linhas

Tags: android

O meu codigo abre um ficheiro txt da net e coloca-o numa textview. O problema é que ele junta as linhas todas. Como fazer para quebrar as linhas?

Outra dúvida é como eliminar as tags do ficheiro de texto e não quebrar os links rtmp e rtmpe. ja que com os http não há nenhum problema ao converter para link

```
package com.tvmix.read; 
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView; 

   public class ReadFileAssetsActivity extends Activity {
    TextView textMsg;
    final String textSource = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/w7ga6shmocr23x4/Eventos.txt?dl=0"; 
    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        textMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textmsg);
        URL textUrl;
        try {
            textUrl = new URL(textSource);
            BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(textUrl.openStream()));
            String StringBuffer;
            String stringText = "";
            while ((StringBuffer = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringText += StringBuffer;
            }
            bufferReader.close();
            textMsg.setText(stringText);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            textMsg.setText(e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            textMsg.setText(e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Formate o código para que o possamos entender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltou você concatenar o caractere de quebra de linha (`\n`) a cada linha que você lê.

Seu loop de leitura ficaria:

```
while ((StringBuffer = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
    stringText += (StringBuffer + "\n");
}
```

Comment: Obrigado resolvido

Answer (score 1):

Você deverá usar "\n" para tabulação, caso queira concatenar com outra informação, você deverá usar o sinal de +

Answer (score 0):

Use o método `setLines`:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setLines%28int%29

ou no xml a propriedade:

```
android:lines
```

Comment: Obrigado mas está resolvido com \n